# Question about the group $\Bbb Z_2 \otimes \Bbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know that $\Bbb Z_2 \otimes \Bbb Z_2$ consists of four elements:
$I = (1,1)$, $A = (-1, 1)$, $B = (1,-1)$ and $C = (-1,-1)$.

But why is the composite cycle: $(14)(23)$ is an element of $\Bbb Z_2 \otimes \Bbb Z_2$ and which one is it ($I, A, B$ or $C$)?

Comment: I think you mean $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. The notation $\Bbb Z_2\otimes\Bbb Z_2$ denotes the tensor product, which is something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different presentations of $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$, all of which are *isomorphic*.  In particular, a group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ if and only if it has a "multiplication" table of the form
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\cdot & e & a & b & c\\
\hline
e & e&a&b&c\\
\hline
a & a & e & c & b\\
\hline
b & b & c & e & a\\
\hline
c & c & b & a & e 
\end{array}
$$
For some four elements $\{a,b,c,e\}$.  Notably, $e$ is the identity element of this group.

The elements $\{(\pm 1, \pm 1)\}$ form a group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ because we can fill in this table with 
$$
e = (1,1), \quad a = (-1,1), \quad b = (1,-1), \quad c = (-1,-1)
$$
Similarly, the set of permutations $\{e,(1\ 4), (2\ 3), (1\ 4)(2\ 3)\} \subset S_4$ form a group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ since we can fill in this table with
$$
e = e, \quad a = (1\ 4), \quad b = (2\ 3), \quad c = (1\ 4)(2\ 3)
$$
As for what the actual elements of $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ are, that's a matter of definition.  Take a very close look at your notes to see what the elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ are.  I'm used to a definition under which $\Bbb Z_2 = \{0,1\}$ and $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2 = \{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$, where the operation is entrywise addition modulo $2$.